# sklearn High score with low performance

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

could you kindly help me decide whether I'm hitting a bug or the problem may be in my implementation?

I have a data set with 5 features and 2000+ observations and I use SVR to do regression tests and select parameters with grid search. If I don't scale my data, then I get a best score of close to zero, but if I do scale it, the best score is around 0.90.

When I manually test the data, it predicts wrong values totally randomly. How can this be? I expect the best score to show how well the trained data could have been validated on new ones during cross validation. I suppose I should not get high score if my model cannot generate well. Should I? Could this be a bug?

SKlearn version is 0.19.1 (from package of Ubuntu Linux 18.04 x64 LTS platform)
Python version is 3.6.7

Would it be worth an upgrade with pip? Any further idea? Thank you.

Edit: see the following code that produces high score, still generalizes badly - though it is regression, scoring should reflect the difference of the predicted ones from the test values:

```
C_range = 2.0 ** np.arange(-5, 15, 2)
gamma_range = 2.0 ** np.arange(-5, 15, 2)
parameters = {"kernel":["rbf"], "C":C_range, "gamma":gamma_range}
estimator = svm.SVR()
clf = GridSearchCV(estimator, parameters, cv=3, n_jobs=-1, verbose=0)
clf.fit(x, y)
print( clf.best_score_ )
```

Comment: Do you also scale your *test* data, before feeding them into the model? And what do you mean "0.90" score? This is regression, not classification...

Comment: Yes I do scale my test data, but I talked about training only with sklearn's built-in cross validation. The score is what sklearn gives back as a result, it should reflect the generalization capability, only it doesn't. It simply makes no sense. I'd appreciate any opinion on this matter. See the following code (Python3), its best score that it can give back is 1, meaning 100% generalization for new data whereas 0 means none:

clf = GridSearchCV(estimator, parameters, cv=3, n_jobs=-1, verbose=0);

clf.fit(x, y);

print( clf.best_score_ )

Comment: Please do not post code in the comments - edit & update your post instead

Comment: Also, according to your own description, you are in a *regression* setting - a score of 1 does *not* mean 100%! Hopefully you see why describing problems verbally (without code) here is **not** a good idea, and seriously diminishes the chances of getting a useful answer...

Comment: I posted code above, thanks. So even regression should provide a score that reflects the difference of the predictions from the test values. Simple. It is the validation scoring, which is (by the documentation) the mean of the validation scores.